# Windows Server 2008 Denial of Service Detection

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, denial-of-service

We have a Windows 2008 server that hosts a file share in which a SQL server database is stored and accessed from another SQL server on the same network.  Periodically, the database become inaccessible and when we check the event logs on the Windows 2008 file server, there is a warning logged with event ID 2025 stating that a denial of service attack was detected.

Is there a way to prevent this, other than disabling the DOS protection?  Is there a way to list the SQL server as a "safe" server or something of that nature?

Can anyone point me to documentation discussing this DOS protection in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking at my firewall to see what kind of DOS features it has. You could also talk to your ISP about blocking certain ranges before they even get to you if they are all coming it from some specific area or IP range.

Doing it from within Windows does not seem like the right place to me.

Comment: This file server is internal only, it's not directly exposed to the internet, but it is accessed by a web server.  We did not turn anything on in Windows to make this start happening.

Comment: OK, I thought it was from outside. This might help you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/898468 If you don't have any real problems, you can disable the message, or reconfigure if it is. That article is for 2003, but is similar.